# Ubuntu - why would /var/log/dmesg stop updating after boot? does not show panic/cpu_hung errors which the console shows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging

So I have an Ubuntu 10.04 install VM on a host.
Latest 2.6.38-15-server kernel .
/var/log/dmesg displays only the bootup but will stop recording after that.
It will not show the trace/cpu_hung errors I am trying to troubleshoot.
/var/log/dmesg.0 , dmesg.1 nothing - I did a string search for the text that displays on the console during the crash and NOTHING gets logged anywhere in /var/log/* .

I have to call into the provider and ask them to take a screenshot of the console since nothing shows in dmesg.

Why would /var/log/dmesg not record kernel panics, or such?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whether you fix kernel logging past boot time or not will not help with kernel panic messages. When your kernel panics, it stops scheduling, so your logging daemon won't ever get to write down the kernel messages. If you want to grab those, you can look into [`kdump`](http://lse.sourceforge.net/kdump/) to get complete kernel core dumps and/or the [`netconsole`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt) kernel module to send the kernel messages over UDP to a remote `syslog` server.

As to getting kernel messages into `/var/log/dmesg` past boot time but outside of serious kernel crashes, try to have something like this in `/etc/syslog.conf` (or `/etc/rsyslog.conf` if using `rsyslog`):

```
kern.* /var/log/dmesg
```

For `rsyslog`, the file must also contain:

```
$ModLoad imklog.so
```

Let me know if you're using `syslog-ng`, it'd be a bit trickier to cover.

Comment: I have imklog.so in /etc/rsyslog.conf - perhaps you are correct - just thought everything was always logged - from console included - but if the system is halted i guess it couldn't write to it anyway

Comment: You also need `kern.* /var/log/dmesg` (and obviously not commented).

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `/var/log/dmesg` is a static file, created at the end of the boot process.

I'm more familiar with Debian, in which the `/etc/init.d/bootmisc.sh` file creates `/var/log/dmesg` in a call to savelog.  Ubuntu does this through `/etc/init/dmesg.conf`.

For system logging during normal operations, you'll want to refer to `/var/log/syslog`, as Pierre Carrier notes.

Since a kernel panic frequently (though not always) breaks user processes (such as syslog) and disk I/O, you'll have to use a kernel logging feature (kdump, netconsole) to capture kernel panics.  Another option is to log via serial console (possibly serial-over-LAN with appropriate IPMI/ILOM support), or with an attached gdb session.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the log Dameon using

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/566366)

Comment: This is the solution, I've used it several times. Test solutions before you comment, forget that I'm new here, I'm an established member on stack overflow.